# Bootstrap Scrollable table body CSS issues?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to create a table from the example at http://www.bootply.com/JnOYtO9xzn# and I've copied everything exact. However the css isn't applying correctly to my table and it's mashing everything together.

This is what's happening:

[image]

Here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-fixed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-2">#</th><th class="col-xs-8">Name</th><th class="col-xs-2">Points</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">1</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td><td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">2</td><td class="col-xs-8">Holly Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">3</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mary Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">86</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">4</td><td class="col-xs-8">Jim Adams</td><td>23</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">5</td><td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">6</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">7</td><td class="col-xs-8">Andy Parks</td><td class="col-xs-2">56</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">8</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Skelly</td><td class="col-xs-2">96</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">9</td><td class="col-xs-8">William Defoe</td><td class="col-xs-2">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">10</td><td class="col-xs-8">Will Tripp</td><td class="col-xs-2">16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">11</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bill Champion</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-xs-2">12</td><td class="col-xs-8">Lastly Jane</td><td class="col-xs-2">6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.table-fixed thead {
width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
height: 230px;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td,                      .table-fixed th {
display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
float: left;
border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to place your code into a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: What is the problem? Its look like okay in my screen.

Comment: reproduce the issue in jsfiddle or similar

Comment: I don't understand. I put it in jsfiddle and it looks fine. But when I run it through my code, it looks like the picture i posted...

Comment: It seems like it's putting all 3 cells into the first cell..